# How to access root directory (/) in android 5.1

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-file

everyone,
I want to build an app scanning all the files in the devices, so I have to access root directory ("/"), but the `file.listfile` returns NULL. Is there any way to access "/"?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the system in a non-root account, whose allowed reading directories are limited. Directory in "/" are only available for `root` users. However, due to security concerns, `root` privilege are generally not accessible for third-party installed apps, in case the installed app may modify system level codes to do bad things.

You may get further information from [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty strange as on an Android 5.1 device it should just do the listing. No root needed.
Also on Android 6 this works on all devices i know.

It only started with Android 7 that `"/"` is not listable anymore.

Which device is it?

Comment: An customized android system, OPENTHOS.